# Start an SQL Server instance without SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I took my SQL Server 2008 offline because I was trying to do something... Now I can't log in to it using SQL Server Management Studio anymore. "The server was not found or was not accessible." I'm not sure exactly what I did, but whatever I did, I need to undo it.

I recall right-clicking on the connection in SMSS and hitting "Stop". Now I can't get it up again.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the SQL Server Windows service.

Start the Services control panel applet (or "services.msc" from Start|Run). Right click on "Services (local)" to connect to the right computer.

Go down the list and start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)", assuming you are using the default instance.

If you cannot connect remotely you will need to visit the machine.

Additional:

- Ensure a firewall is not blocking connections.
- Ensure the network protocol you are using is enabled on the server (full SQL Server has an app for this).
- Can you connect locally?

Comment: I'm using SQLEXPRESS and service "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is already started. I tried restarting it as well, with no luck.

Comment: Expanded... in the end I think you will have to go back to basics and double check everything (starting with anything you are assuming: e.g. check the process exists, not just the service is running).

Answer (score 1):

Check what you did against this article:

[SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: Sorry, none of those tips solved the problem. Some of them don't even apply to me since I'm connecting to the server locally. I recall right-clicking on the connection in SMSS and hitting "Stop". Now I can't get it up again.

Comment: If you're connected locally, then have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, I tried rebooting, but no cigar.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing Start?

Comment: Anything in the Error Log?

Comment: No *errors* per se, but it says "Server name is 'ABCDEF\SQLEXPRESS'" (faked ABCDEF) which is not correct!  The name should be something else.  I *am* able to connect to ABCDEF\SQLEXPRESS but not to the right name!

Comment: I think you're now on the way to finding out what was changed and what is ABCDEF.

Comment: Apparently I was remote desktoping to the wrong computer. *facepalm* Thanks.